# How to merge polygons into a single pad?

Tags: pcb, altium, footprint

I need to create a pad in a PCB footprint, This pad is created using these 3 polygons but I dont know how to merge them together into one pad. I am using Altium 17.
[image: 3 polygons]

**edit**
[image: one polygon]
Thanks to Chris's comment,It can be done using a more 'poly' polygon.
Now I need to add pad number/designator to the pad.

Comment: In most packages, you'd create a polygon with that shape, not merge rectangles.  See if you can figure out how to make polygons that are a bit more "poly"

Comment: Thanks Chris, wondering how to add a designator to the new pad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to make sure all your polygons are overlapping (to make sure they are connected) and then drop down a small pad anywhere within the polygon.  Is this what you're looking for?

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-custom-pad-shapes-ad?version=18.1

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful link, however this is a surface mount pad for a component...I managed to create it as one copper polygon like Chris's comment, now I want to add designators like any standard pads.

Comment: He said "drop down a small pad...".  So it will be a surface mount pad.

Comment: Dan is correct, place a surface-mount pad in the center of the polygon. It will effectively turn your shape into one large pad since it will all be electrically connected.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.